# "docker-compose build" is showing me help text when I specify a file

Tags: docker, yaml, docker-compose

When I specify a compose file during build:

`docker-compose build -f compose-production.yml`

the images don't get built, and in stead I'm shown help-text:

```
$ docker-compose build -f compose-production.yml 
Build or rebuild services.

Services are built once and then tagged as `project_service`,
e.g. `composetest_db`. If you change a service's `Dockerfile` or the
contents of its build directory, you can run `docker-compose build` to rebuild it.

Usage: build [options] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    --force-rm  Always remove intermediate containers.
    --no-cache  Do not use cache when building the image.
    --pull      Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image.
```

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run with:

```
docker-compose -f compose-production.yml build
```

`-f` is option for `docker-compose` not option for command `build`

Comment: Such trivial, such difficulty to find in `docker-compose build` docs :(